# A Problem about Spliting of Exact Sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

*Module Case*
Let
$$0\rightarrow N \stackrel f \rightarrow G\stackrel g \rightarrow Q\rightarrow 0$$
be the exact $R$-module sequence iff

> (1) there exists $u:G\rightarrow N$ which satisfies $u\circ f=id_N$.
>
> (2) there exists $v:Q\rightarrow G$ which satisfies $g\circ v=id_Q$.
>
> (3) $G\cong N\times Q$.
>
> Furthermore, we can make
>   $$0\leftarrow N \stackrel u \leftarrow G\stackrel v \leftarrow Q\leftarrow 0$$
>   exact.
>
> ---

*Group Case*
Let
$$1\rightarrow N \stackrel f \rightarrow G\stackrel g \rightarrow Q\rightarrow 1$$
be the exact group sequence iff

> (1) there exists $u:G\rightarrow N$ which satisfies $u\circ f=id_N$.
>
> (2) there exists $v:Q\rightarrow G$ which satisfies $g\circ v=id_Q$.
>
> (3) $G\cong N\ltimes Q$.
>
> ---

My question is that

> Does the *Group Case* have the *Furthermore* Property in *Module Case*?

Comment: I assume you mean that the sequence is $split$ exact in those cases, not just exact. And no, in general, we cannot get the last part for groups, since the image of $Q$ in $G$ need not be normal.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you for the analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instructive example for the group case is 
$$ 0\to \mathbb Z/3\stackrel f\longrightarrow S_3\stackrel g\longrightarrow  \mathbb Z/2\to 0$$
where $f(1+\mathbb Z)=(1\ 2\ 3)$. 
Then we have $u\colon \mathbb Z/2\to S_3$, $1+\mathbb Z\mapsto (1\ 2)$ is a right split, but there does not exist a left split (and the action of $\mathbb Z/2$ on $\mathbb Z/3$ is the only possible one: map to inverse)